# Classifying Stationary point of constrained problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following problem:

Find and classify the stationary points of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the constraint $x^2+2y^2-z^2 = 1$.

Using Lagrange multipliers, I found that $(0,\pm 1/\sqrt{2},0)$ and $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$ are the stationary points, but what is the method to determine the nature of these points in general?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the extended (or bordered) Hessian, which is of the form
$$
H(a,\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &-J_g(a) \\-J_g(a)^T & H_L(a)\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $J_g(a)$ is the Jacobian matrix of the constraints at a given stationary point $a$ and $H_L(a)$ is the Hessian matrix of the Lagrangian function, with respect to the initial variables (not the Lagrange multipliers). In you case, assuming $L = x^2+y^2+z^2 - \lambda(x^2+2y^2-z^2-1)$, this would lead to
$$
H(x,y,z; \lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2x & 4y & -2z \\
2x & 2-2\lambda & 0 & 0\\
4y & 0 &2-4\lambda& 0 \\
-2z & 0 & 0 & 2+2 \lambda
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

When you have $p$ restrictions and $m$ variables, you can classify the critical points by looking at
$$
(-1)^p \Delta_{2p+1}, \cdots, (-1)^p \Delta_{p+m}
$$

where  $\Delta_k$ is the determinant of the principal minor of order $k$.

1. If all those numbers are positive, you have a (local) constrained minimum.
2. If $(-1)^p\Delta_{2p+1} <0$ and the signs alternate after that, you have a (local) constrained maximum.

In this particular case, this leads to the conclusion that both  $(0,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$ and $(\pm 1,0,0)$ are local minimum points. In the image below you can see the critical points, the origin,together with a representation of the constraint.

[image]